# how to force a stored procedure be pre-cached and stay in memory?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, caching, autostart

Stored procedures are compiled on first use.

There are options to clear cache:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
--To Verify whether the cache is emptied
--DBCC PROCCACHE
```

or to recompile or to reduce recompilations.

But is it possible to force frequently used stored procedures' execution plans be pre-cached and stay in memory?

I know how to do it in ADO.NET, i.e. from outside of SQL Server, but this question is how to do inside SQL Server - to be launched with the start of SQL Server itself.

(*) For example, I see in SSMS Activity Monitor a running process (Task State: RUNNING, Command: SELECT) that is continuously executing T-SQL (according to Profiler) in context of tempdb database though SQL Server Agent is disabled and SQL Server is not loaded by anything, see "Details of session 54" in "[Where are all those SQL Server sessions from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021428/where-are-all-those-sql-server-sessions-from)".

How would I do the similar resident process (or, rather, auto-starting by SQL Server start service or session) periodically recycling stored procedure?

Related question:
[Stored procedure executes slowly on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011344/stored-procedure-executes-slowly-on-first-run)

Update:
Might be I should have forked this question in 2 but my main curiosity is how to have periodic/ looping activity with SQL Server Agent disabled?
How was it made with mentioned above RUNNING SELECT session  (*)?

**Update2:**
Frequently  I observe considerable delays while executing stored procedures  querying very small amount of data which cannot be explained only through necessity to read huge amounts of data.

Can we consider this - considerable delays on insignificantly small data - as context of this question?

Comment: As opposed to the execution plan being cached, more often than not, it's having the data cached in memory that offers the biggest gain in performance (hence ideal world = have all the data in memory) as that prevents disk being hit

Comment: @vgv8: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Also note to be aware of, sometimes you may want a sproc to be recompiled instead of using a plan from the cache

Comment: Near duplicate, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002576/sql-server-cache-question

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I cannot want to make something impossible.  Also, wanting to understand or having (un)healthy curiosity is not synonym of wanting to make. Curiosity is the engine of innovation and progress. Have I correctly answered your question?

Comment: @vgv8: I wasn't suggesting that curiosity was a bad thing. Forcing a query plan to stay in the cache could actually be detrimental in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this question eventually got answered in:

- [Can I get SQL Server to call a stored proc every n seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079363/can-i-get-sql-server-to-call-a-stored-proc-every-n-seconds)

Update:  These tips will do the trick:

- [Keeping data available in the SQL Server data cache with PINTABLE](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1317)
- [Automatically Running Stored Procedures at SQL Server Startup](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1574)

Answer (score 0):

Just execute it from a script. You could do this after any sql server restart. If they are frequently used, it shouldn't be much of a problem after that.

Comment: won't guarantee that it stays in the cache though, unless it is hit continuously over and above other activity