# Can I get SQL Server to call a stored proc every n seconds?

Tags: sql-server

I wish to have a stored proc that is called every n seconds, is there a way to do this in SQL Server without depending on a separate process?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) and [activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx). No external process, continues to work after a clustering or mirroring failover, continues to work even after a restore on a different machine, and it works on Express too.

```
-- create a table to store the results of some dummy procedure
create table Activity (
    InvokeTime datetime not null default getdate()
    , data float not null);
go  

-- create a dummy procedure
create procedure createSomeActivity
as
begin
    insert into Activity (data) values (rand());
end
go

-- set up the queue for activation
create queue Timers;
create service Timers on queue Timers ([DEFAULT]);
go

-- the activated procedure
create procedure ActivatedTimers
as
begin
declare @mt sysname, @h uniqueidentifier;
begin transaction;
    receive top (1)
        @mt = message_type_name
        , @h = conversation_handle
        from Timers;

    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        commit transaction;
        return;
    end

    if @mt in (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
        , N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
    begin
        end conversation @h;
    end
    else if @mt = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer'
    begin
        exec createSomeActivity;
        -- set a new timer after 2s
        begin conversation timer (@h) timeout = 2;
    end
commit
end
go

-- attach the activated procedure to the queue
alter queue Timers with activation (
    status = on
    , max_queue_readers = 1
    , execute as owner
    , procedure_name = ActivatedTimers);
go  


-- seed a conversation to start activating every 2s
declare @h uniqueidentifier;
begin dialog conversation @h
    from service [Timers]
    to service N'Timers', N'current database'
    with encryption = off;
begin conversation timer (@h) timeout = 1;

-- wait 15 seconds
waitfor delay '00:00:15';

-- end the conversation, will stop activating
end conversation @h;
go

-- check that the procedure executed
select * from Activity;
```

Comment: But that requires you to have the Service Broker bits installed and enabled (which are optional, too), no?? How is this any better than SQL Agent??

Comment: Service Broker bits are part of the SQL Server engine itself (not optional install). Individual databases can have SSB disabled, but by default is enabled in every DB except master and model. Is it fully contained inside a DB (no msdb dependencies) so it can travel as a backup/restore to a new host. It survives DB mirroring failover w/o any problem, again because no msdb dependencies. It scales and performs *way* better than SQL Agent. It has self load-balancing capabilities via max_queue_readers. Activation is push based, not pull. Is in every SQL Express. And the list goes on and on.

Comment: If I want this to run continuously forever, how do I "self-restart" on conversation lifetime expiration or error? I tried duplicating the `BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION` block inside the sproc, but it didn't work. (I'm not an expert at this.)

Comment: @JonSeigel You issue another `BEGIN DIALOG TIMER` on the same handle (ie. you RECEIVE in activated proc and arm the timer again on the same handle you got from RECEIVE). A conversation can have at most one timer active, but once the timer fires you can arm it again, and then again and then again. On error is more tricky, as it largely depends on the nature of the error.

Comment: I was looking at your blog post [here](http://rusanu.com/2007/12/03/resending-messages). Out of the 4 errors you suggest to initiate re-send, the only ones I care about are 8489 (dialog has exceeded the specified LIFETIME), and if possible, 9719 (database for this conversation endpoint is attached or restored). I'm not sure if the latter even applies to this scenario. Essentially, I want this to run *forever* very reliably without anyone ever having to manually bootstrap it again after I start it initially. I'm planning to use this setup as the heartbeat for a job engine within our DB.

Comment: @JonSeigel: that's right. Most other errors can occur only if the conversations have both endpoints established (ie. initiator did `SEND` a message and cause the target to be created). A timer-only conversation has only initiator endpoint, so most errors simply don't apply.

Comment: Okay, your comment about only one side of the conversation gave me a hint. I had tested the code only by using `END CONVERSATION ...` which would simply kill the whole thing. Instead, I set a lifetime to the conversation, and then using `BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION` inside the proc works. The code is also able to trap 9719 on restore, which is great. The only scenario it doesn't work is if using `RESTORE ... WITH NEW_BROKER` -- is it possible to handle that?

Comment: `NEW_BROKER` is da bomb (`RESTORE ... WITH NEW_BROKER` as well as `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER`). You can't possibly automatically recover from *that*. You need to provide a stored proc to 'seed' the whole system, start the first timer, and whoever does `NEW_BROKER` must properly restart it.

Comment: I'm trying to see why using the *lifetime* instead of timer gives me an uneasy feeling... All my implementations I did `BEGIN CONVERSATION ... ` once, `BEGIN TIMER...` to seed it and then re-issue `BEGIN TIMER ...` inside the activation. You need to handle two messages (Error *and* Timer) but I think is cleaner, it better conveys the intent to a reviewer 5 years down the road.

Comment: Re `NEW_BROKER`: okay, that's what I figured. Yeah, I'm only setting a lifetime for proof-of-concept testing (15 seconds). In the actual code, I'll set it to max. I know the default you said is like 60+ years, I just want to handle that because it's reasonable to do so. Oh, also, regarding your last comment, is it safe to remove the `EndDialog` handling? I wasn't able to hit that branch of the IF while testing (I modified your code to split the `EndDialog` and `Error` test into two separate branches).

Comment: Unless you have an objection (or want to do it yourself), I'm going to edit this post to include a check of `@@ROWCOUNT` after the `RECEIVE` to handle the drained queue call of the sproc (technically it isn't required in the code above, but it's good for safety in case others like me modify it without realizing this happens). I didn't want to edit without asking you first.

Comment: The empty result set in the example is handled by the IF cases (ie. it does not match any if case). Just adding a `@@ROWCOUNT` check is not enough to make it a 'production ready', there are many more things to consider (TRY/CATCH, handle being activated on a disabled queue, logging of result etc). I had on my backstove a post of a template for an activated procedure that should be 'production quality' as an example, never have time to finish it though. I appreciate you asking first and you can go ahead and do the edit. I just wanted to be aware that there are many trolls under that bridge...

Comment: Thanks; I edited the answer. Although I've mostly gone through the motions already, a much more solid template would be very helpful to compare with.

Comment: Do you know how `sys.conversation_endpoints.dialog_timer` can get reset to `19000101` on its own in this setup? Possibly related to many DBs having it running? If I start this up on one DB manually, it works just fine, but when I have lots of DBs (9-30) in the same instance, after a DB update (applied to DBs sequentially), it either doesn't work at all, or starts and then randomly stops later. No errors in the Error Log, no server restarts, and the queue is still enabled (poison message handling is enabled). A `DialogTimer` message is stuck in the queue as nothing is firing to process it.

Comment: What is the state of sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors? Looks like http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/

Comment: As for the `dialog_timer` being reset, this is normal if you have a DialogTimer message in the queue. The timer fired, it enqueued the message and reset itself. The real problem is the lack of activation, for which the linked article above explain the cause and supplies some investigation clues.

Comment: For the databases that aren't working, there are no rows in `sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors`. I have a timer queue and an execution queue -- there should be *two* rows in the DMV, but there are none. I checked all the settings in the blog post and they are fine. Those settings also match identically between databases that do and don't work. I'm on 2008 R2 (SP1 and SP2) if that makes a difference.

Comment: r u sure the queues don't disable due to poison message handling? If sys.service_queues.is_receive_enables is 1 and is_activation_enabled is 1 yet no row in sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors then is something I cannot offer any advice on, you may need to contact CSS.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. It's identical code running on all DBs, and there's no user-defined input at this level. In the last release I tried to fix this by not only enabling/disabling activation but also flipping the queue status itself (i.e., `ALTER QUEUE ... WITH STATUS = OFF`). This worked for me in dev, and ad-hoc in a live DB. I'm going to go back and verify that it works using our DB update program. With the old code, manually running commands from SSMS wouldn't hold. I thought there was something fishy going on under the hood based on what was happening.

Comment: A little update: I reproduced the problematic behaviour using our database update program. The initial creation scripts left the timer queue in an invalid state, and then in my subsequent update, it left the other queue in an invalid state as well. While the queues are in an invalid state, my attempt to disable and then re-enable them within the same transaction (in the DB update program) doesn't work, but if each part is in its own transaction (when I run it ad-hoc), it works fine. I still have to narrow down the case to figure out how the queues got into that state in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

You can set up a SQL Agent job - that's probably the only way to go.

[SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) is a component of SQL Server - not available in the Express editions, however - which allows you to automate certain tasks, like database maintenance etc. but you can also use it to call stored procs every n seconds.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I see too many servers that have Sql Agent process not running to trust it.  I was hoping for something built into SqlServer it's self.

Comment: Sql Server Agent is an **optional** part of SQL server that is often disabled on servers.  (I don't turst our customers!)

Answer (score 2):

I once set up a stored procedure that ran continuously, uisng a loop with a WAITFOR at the end of it.

- The WHILE condition depended upon the value read from a simple configuration table. If the value got set to 0, the loop would be exited and the procedure finished.
- I put a WAITFOR DELAY at the end, so that however long it took to process a given iteration, it would wait XX seconds until it ran it again. (XX was also set in and read from the configuration table.)
- If it must run at precise intervales (say, 0, 15, 30, and 45 seconds in the minute), you could calculate the appropriate WATIFOR TIME value at the end of the loop.
- Lastly, I had the procedure called by a SQL Agent job once a minute. The job would always be "running" showing that the procedure was running.  If the procedure was killed or crashed, the job would start it up in no more than 1 minute.  If the procedure was "turned off", the procedure still gets run but the WHILE loop containing the processing does not get entered making the overhead nill.

I didn't much like having it in my database, but it fulfilled the business requirements.

Comment: Just read the other comments.  If not SQL Agent, what do you use to ensure that the process is always running?  And no matter what you write, both skilled admins and hapless stooges can mess with your careful preparations.

Answer (score 0):

```
WAITFOR   
{  
    DELAY 'time_to_pass'   
  | TIME 'time_to_execute'   
  | [ ( receive_statement ) | ( get_conversation_group_statement ) ]   
    [ , TIMEOUT timeout ]  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to keep a SSMS query window open:

```
While 1=1
Begin
exec "Procedure name here" ;
waitfor delay '00:00:15';
End
```

Comment: ... or even two SSMS windows, for High Availability?