# Execute the script itself in every 5 min by getting the system time

Tags: sql-server

**I want to write a script that will execute in every 5 min, and based on that certain actons will perform.**

To be more clearify we take a simple example of inserting tha data in the table:

**Insert into EmpDetails(id, Name, Designation) values (1, 'ABC', 'Developer')**

I just want to insert the same data in every 5 min according to my system time.

Can anyone please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably it's the answer [Can I get SQL Server to call a stored proc every n seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079363/can-i-get-sql-server-to-call-a-stored-proc-every-n-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The BEST solution is running using **SQL Agent Jobs**

1. Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select `'New Job'`
2. In the `'New Job'` window enter the name of the job and a description on the `'General'` tab.
3. Select `'Steps'` on the left hand side of the window and click `'New'` at the bottom.
4. In the `'Steps'` window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.
5. Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click `'OK'`.
6. Click on the `'Schedule'` menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time).
7. Click `'OK'` - and that should be it.

(There are of course other options you can add - but I would say that is the bare minimum you need to get a job set up and scheduled)

[Pulled from Previous SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Jobs and shcedule for 5 minutes . In case you have the feature enable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a script.  After creating the job in the agent job section, or via script, this can all be automated.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = 'Your_schedule_name',
    @freq_type=4,       -- daily
    @freq_interval = 1,     -- every day
    @freq_subday_type=4,    -- Minutes
    @freq_subday_interval = 5   -- every 5 minutes
```

Then attach the schedule

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule  
   @job_name = N'Your_job_name',  
   @schedule_name = N'Your_schedule_name' ;
```