# Trying to run a SQL Server stored procedure every n seconds using Activation and Timers not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, timer, queue

I'm trying to run a stored procedure every few seconds that'll do some maintenance (move some rows from a staging to production table). I've looked at [this answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079716/386703) and not been able to get it to work on SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition. I read through the comments and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079363/can-i-get-sql-server-to-call-a-stored-proc-every-n-seconds#comment46441387_4079716) from another user, where the original question answerer suggested he ask a separate question. I didn't find a separate question from him about it.

I copied the example directly from the other question into SQL Server but it would always return zero rows on the last statement. Here is the SQL provided by the other question:

```
-- create a table to store the results of some dummy procedure
create table Activity (
    InvokeTime datetime not null default getdate()
    , data float not null);
go  

-- create a dummy procedure
create procedure createSomeActivity
as
begin
    insert into Activity (data) values (rand());
end
go

-- set up the queue for activation
create queue Timers;
create service Timers on queue Timers ([DEFAULT]);
go

-- the activated procedure
create procedure ActivatedTimers
as
begin
declare @mt sysname, @h uniqueidentifier;
begin transaction;
    receive top (1)
        @mt = message_type_name
        , @h = conversation_handle
        from Timers;

    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        commit transaction;
        return;
    end

    if @mt in (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
        , N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
    begin
        end conversation @h;
    end
    else if @mt = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer'
    begin
        exec createSomeActivity;
        -- set a new timer after 2s
        begin conversation timer (@h) timeout = 2;
    end
commit
end
go

-- attach the activated procedure to the queue
alter queue Timers with activation (
    status = on
    , max_queue_readers = 1
    , execute as owner
    , procedure_name = ActivatedTimers);
go  


-- seed a conversation to start activating every 2s
declare @h uniqueidentifier;
begin dialog conversation @h
    from service [Timers]
    to service N'Timers', N'current database'
    with encryption = off;
begin conversation timer (@h) timeout = 1;

-- wait 15 seconds
waitfor delay '00:00:15';

-- end the conversation, will stop activating
end conversation @h;
go

-- check that the procedure executed
select * from Activity;
```

The `begin dialog conversation @h` statement will return me a proper uniqueidentifier that I'm able to use in the `end conversation` call, but it seems like nothing is ever being placed into the queue.

Comment: I copied your code about without any changes and it worked ok for me, generated some data in the Activity table. Before I ran your code I did create database test
go
use test
go
create table Activity(data float)
go  and then your code without any changes worked OK

Comment: Which version of SQL Server though?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
 Express Edition (64-bit)

Comment: That's curious... I'm running Enterprise and if I paste exactly what I have, nothing happens. I edited the question to add some code that I missed from the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by shurik, I tested this on a database that I created simply with

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
```

and everything worked. I took a look at the `CREATE` script for the database I was developing against (which I created through the SSMS UI) and noticed that the script contained

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASENAME] SET DISABLE_BROKER
GO
```

meaning, obviously, that the broker is disabled for my database. I found it odd because I didn't explicitly disable the broker when creating my database in the UI.

I scripted the `CREATE` of the table I created with the `CREATE` statement and noticed that the option

```
ALTER DATABASE [TestDB] SET ENABLE_BROKER
GO
```

was in the script.

Basically, any database created through the SSMS UI will have the broker disabled by default (I checked with a new database), and any database created through a `CREATE` statement will have it enabled by default.

I'm surprised that through trying to get it to work I never once got a notification that the broker was disabled.