# How to write a stored procedure in SQL Server to change the columns value after a specific time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

I have created a table using the following query in SQL Server database `Appointment-20160925160528` for doctor appointment schedule

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[doctorschedule1]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [date] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [8:00Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [8:15Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [8:30Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [8:45Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [9:00Am] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

There are five columns named `| 8:00AM | 8:15AM | 8:30AM | 8:45AM | 9:00AM |`
AND the value of the column are

```
| Booked | Available | Available | Booked | Available |
```

After creating the table the table look like this:

<kbd>8:00 AM</kbd><kbd>8:15 AM</kbd><kbd>8:30 AM</kbd><kbd>8:45AM</kbd> <kbd>8:00.. AM</kbd>
<kbd>Booked</kbd><kbd>Available</kbd><kbd>Available</kbd><kbd>Booked</kbd> <kbd>Available</kbd>

Now I want to change the value of the column ***8:00AM*** from **Booked** to **Available** if the current time of the system  is 7 hours 44 minutes and 59 seconds 7:44:59 AM

How to write a stored procedure that check the current system time and then change the column value? As I am very new to SQL Server databases. Any working example will be very helpful for me and bundle of thanks for your great time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079363/can-i-get-sql-server-to-call-a-stored-proc-every-n-seconds link may help

Comment: @DeepakSharma thanks for the link, interesting solution!

Comment: Another way is to use job, that will on some schedule make changes you need.

Comment: Yeap. if you have knowledge of windows programming then window/Task scheduler will be best for this

Comment: You seem to have designed this table based on a form layout or similar. You've got *data* embedded in your column *names* (metadata). You'll come to find that writing queries against such a table will prove troublesome. You should design your tables around your data. In this case, there ought to be a single column for `appointment time`, another column for `appointment status` and then multiple *rows* describing each appointment.

Comment: Rethink about your design. You'll have many problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want to optimize this, create another table with a timestamp column and insert values there when an appoinment occurs and delete your current table. What you are doing is pretty ugly and inefficient.

To your question, do it in your application. Check your current time, if its higher then all of the values listed, Update them accordingly