# SQL Server stored procedure that includes query from linked server runs in query window but not via Service Broker queue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, service-broker

I have a stored procedure that runs a simple select query against a linked server, which runs fine in the query editor. I need this procedure to run every 5 seconds, and have successfully followed the excellent post from [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) re [calling a stored procedure to run every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079716/8074737) and have his sample procedure running fine.

However, when attempting to run my stored procedure containing the linked server query, it fails with an error

> Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted

I am using "execute as owner" for activation. The remote (linked) server uses Windows Authentication Mode, and is in the same domain. The Windows account I use to logon to the local SQL Server also has rights on the remote server. I don't understand why the stored procedure works in the query editor and not when called via activation.

What am I missing here?

Comment: For troubleshooting, try changing turning TRUSTWORTHY on in your user database. What is the linked server security configuration?

Comment: Linked server uses Windows Authentication. Turning on TRUSTWORTHY results in a different error message: 'Linked servers cannot be used under an impersonation without a mapping for the impersonated login'. I have tried having the local SQL windows login account mapped to a windows account on the remote server that has login rights on that server, using impersonation. However, authentication of windows accounts on the linked server fail. They work fine for connecting to the linked server database engine in SSMS.

Comment: The `execute as owner` mode switches security context to the owner of the schema your queue belongs to. If it's `dbo`, it is a login that owns your database, so check the database owner. For `sa`, that would be the user account the SQL Server instance runs under. Regardless, you might need to set additional permissions in AD for that user / group to allow impersonation.